# I have a problem for finding "Problems" tab analogue in Netbeans IDE

Tags: netbeans, netbeans6.8

I used Eclipse for several years and now I'm trying to switch to Netbeans.
Amazingally, I have had very nice experience while switching :)

One thing I wonder about - is there any eclipse-like "Problems" tabs available in the Netbeans.

Please see ["Problems" tabs image](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-eclipse-osxjava/figure3.jpg) if you have no idea that this is all about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use the Tasks items of the Window menu...

Comment: Thanks a lot for you response.

I really appreciate that

Answer (score 0):

The reason I asked this question was - I did my research first and could not dig any information on topic.

And 5 minutes after this post.. vuala, it's all here [link text](http://osdir.com/ml/java.netbeans.netcat/2007-10/msg00668.html).
That a shame :)